# android json post to php

Tags: php, android, json

I have done raw rest get and post and also could do post in namevaluepair but no matter which tutorial i follow i just cant get json post done ...

**Android Application:**

```
ArrayList<String> stringData = new ArrayList<String>();
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.10/people.php");     

JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
holder.put("name", "Foo");    
holder.put("occupation", "Bar");

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
postMethod.setEntity(se);
postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
postMethod.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

ResponseHandler <String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response=httpClient.execute(postMethod,resonseHandler); 
stringData.add(response);

return stringData;
```

**PHP file:**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

 var_dump($_POST);
}
```

the var_dump just gives an empty array and $_POST["name"] gives undefined index ... any help would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to ship the `holder.toString()` with `BasicNameValuePair` class?

Like

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myjson", holder.toString());
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

then just in your php you get it like

```
$jsonstring = $_REQUEST['myjson'];
```

Comment: Maybe you need to decode it in your php code. If decoding is needed use `$jsonstring = urldecode($_REQUEST['myjson'];`

Comment: This answer is useful for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Two additional ways to read POST data:

1. Read from **php://input**
2. Use var $HTTP_POST_RAW_DATA.

Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be the url you are using.

Post to 10.0.2.2 instead of the one you specified in your http post.